# Comma-separated values to rows with sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table #t(org varchar(50), area int)

insert into #t values ('a', 500), ('b', 200), ('c', 400)

select * from #t
```

Output:

```
org     area
--------------
a       500
b       200
c       400
```

I want to convert the output to this format:

```
org         area
-----------------
a,b,c       1100
```

i.e. comma-separated all the orgs and sum of it's area value.

Comment: If 2017+ take a peek at string_agg()   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  Otherwise you may want the stuff()/XM approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-query is really not necessary :

```
select stuff((select ','+t1.org from #t t1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as org, 
       sum(area) as area
from #t t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a SubQuery/CTE, a window function `SUM() OVER()`, and `STRING_AGG()`

```
create table #t(org varchar(50), area int)
insert into #t values ('a',500),('b',200),('c',400);


select string_agg(org, ',') org, area
from
(
  select org, sum(area) over() area
  from #t
)t
group by area
```

or

```
select org, sum(area) area
from
(
select stuff(
      (select ',' + org from #t  for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') org, area
from #t tt
) t
group by org
```

Answer (score 0):

If use sql server upper than 2017, you can use `String_agg()`

```
create table #t(org varchar(50), area int)
insert into #t values ('a',500),('b',200),('c',400)
select String_agg(org, ',') as org, Sum(area) as sumarea 
from #t
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using sql server 2008 so String_agg is not available over there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query in two parts as shown below.

In the first part get all the values in the comma-separated and in a final query select the sum of all the values of the area.

```
create table #t(org varchar(50), area int)
insert into #t values ('a', 500), ('b', 200), ('c', 400)

DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + org 
FROM   #t --For getting values in comma separated

SELECT @List as AllValues
   , sum(area) as Total
from #t
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f467799761e92ddd2096f7a03c25492) demo.